# Put ajax on hold in VanillaJS

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to put ajax on hold based on the state change? Any help will be appreciated!

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

myRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
            var state = myRequest.readyState,
            //if state === 2 wait for 5 secs and then continue???


}   

myRequest.open("GET", "forAjax.html", true);
myRequest.send();
```

Comment: do you need `setTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, but timeout will be executed after ajax. That is the question how to put it on hold?

Comment: Question is not clear. You just call setTimeout in onreadystatechange function. What's the problem?